# MVC.Net Custom registration/login error "The salt was not in an expected format of {int}.{string}"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need your help. I'm trying to make a custom registration/login in MVC.Net, which uses SimpleCripto to encrypt the passwords. After I register a user everything is saved in my [table](http://prntscr.com/divn5m) and it seems all right, but when I try to LogIn I get an error - "The salt was not in an expected format of {int}.{string}", which comes from my "IsValid" method, in the statement "if (user.Password == crypto.Compute(user.PasswordSalt, password))". I'll post my AuthenticantionController with the Register and LogIn methods and if you can point where the problem is and how to solve it I'll be grateful. Thanks in advance !

```
namespace Final.Controllers
{
    public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LogIn()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogIn(Models.User user)
        {
            if (IsValid(user.Email, user.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login details are wrong.");
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(Models.User user)
        {
            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using (AppContext db = new AppContext())
                    {
                        var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
                        var encrypPass = crypto.Compute(user.Password);

                        var newUser = db.Users.Create();
                        newUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                        newUser.LastName = user.LastName;
                        newUser.Email = user.Email;
                        newUser.CompanyName = user.CompanyName;
                        newUser.Password = encrypPass;
                        newUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;
                        newUser.AdminCode = 0;
                        user.Password = encrypPass;
                        user.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;

                        db.Users.Add(newUser);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Data is not correct");
                }
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation(
                              "Class: {0}, Property: {1}, Error: {2}",
                              validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                              validationError.PropertyName,
                              validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
        }

        private bool IsValid(string email, string password)
        {
            var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
            bool IsValid = false;

            using (AppContext db = new AppContext())
            {
                var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    if (user.Password == crypto.Compute(user.PasswordSalt, password))
                    {
                        IsValid = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return IsValid;
        }

        public ActionResult LogOut()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the `crypto.Compute` function parameters. It requires textToHash(which is your password) and salt. You have to interchange the parameters.

you need to modify your `IsValid` function like this:

```
private bool IsValid(string email, string password)
{
    var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
    bool IsValid = false;

    using (AppContext db = new AppContext())
    {
        var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (user.Password == crypto.Compute(password, user.PasswordSalt))
            {
                IsValid = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return IsValid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. It did the job, but I don't have enough reputation to give you the vote ! So the problem was in the order of the parameters, is that right ? Thanks once again :)